# Od (Ovadyia) Yosef Chai - what is the idea behind the movement

Tags: rabbis

I saw in Tzfat a car adorned with signs saying עוד יוסף חי - with a big picture of Rav [Ovadia Yosef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovadia_Yosef). I was informed by someone going to Yeshiva there that this is some kind of nascent Jewish (not political) movement, perhaps something extreme.

Is this a movement, or just someone with a sign on his car? If it is a movement, what is the philosophy and agenda of this movement?

Comment: I guess you never found out? I've also seen these things...